# OpenGL: How to pass vectors with variable size to shaders?

Tags: opengl

What is an efficient way to pass a variably sized data (which is not unique for each vertex, but rather is common to groups of vertices) into shaders?

For example, I have three polygons with different numbers of vertices. Each polygon has a different color and is colored uniformly (each polygon's fragment has the same color). It seems ineffective to pass the polygon's color in the vertices attributes as a vector containing the same color values for each vertex in polygon. My thought is to assign to each polygon a unique number (starting from zero), create a vector with three color values (one color for each polygon), and to pass for each vertex not a color value (four floats), but the polygon number which the vertex belongs to (one integer). And have the shader fetch the polygon color from the color's vector using the polygon number as the index.

The color values for polygons can be passed in a vector of a variable length (vector whose size is not specified during compilation) through a "Shader Storage Block" where it can be accessed by the shader.

Is there other method (maybe commonly used technique) for passing variably sized vectors to shaders?

Comment: This could save on storage, but it's not really what you would call efficient. Fetching anything in a vertex shader will introduce memory latency that would not be necessary if the attributes were duplicated per-vertex. Shaders work best when they are fed all of the necessary data ***before*** any work begins and not have to wait for a dynamic/indirect fetch at run-time. Is your absolute end-goal here simply to save memory by not duplicating these attributes?

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman - the remark about memory latency during fetching values is useful. But larger arrays seem also take longer to copy into the card memory, and also maybe color values may only be read for the first vertex in polygon and cached for the others. Looks like the efficiency in the case with polygon colors depends on how many vertices each polygon has (how many duplicated data there is in vertex attributes for each polygon ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is precisely the use case of [Buffer Texture Objects](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Texture).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is to manage the color apart from the vertex data and pass it ass a uniform to the shader. But only if the color is the same for each vertex in the vector. If however the color changes for every primitive (or each vertex) don't mind, the overhead implied by the computation with indexing etc. is way worse than simply having to flush the data on a per vertex basis to your video memory! (Unless this is already your bottleneck, but it shouldn't really be with nowadays hardware)

To rapidly flush the data from the vector for rendering, the best approach is to create a 
[vertex buffer object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object).

You basically create a large pool of vertices (and indices, depending on your precise use). Using glDrawElements (or glDrawArray) you can control how many primitive of what type shall be rendered.

Reserve a vertex buffer object with the maximal assumed size of memory you may require in the advance, so you avoid the overhead of recreating it again and again. Initialize the number of primitives to render, to 0. Each time the vector changes, copy the data to the vertex buffer object, from the first vertex to the last in the vector. Modify the number of primitives to be rendered. That's it, the complete overhead left is only flushing the vector to the vertex buffer object. No complex bookkeeping or similar required.

Comment: This is exactly what I do now for the position data for vertices. And along with the array of position attributes, I copy to the VBO also another array of the same size with the color attribute for each vertex. If there are many identical values in the color vector, maybe there is a room for some optimization.

Comment: Having the color and position information separated has performance implications for caching (the memory block must be read from two  different locations for each vertex). Interleaving this information ( vertex 1: 3 floats position & 1 int color, vertex 2: 3 floats position & 1 int color, ....) should already improve a lot. (Depending on the amount of data we are talking here. What is the number of vertices approximately in your case?)

Comment: I'm trying to make a C++ wrapper for some OpenGL functionality and don't have some particular case in view. It seems that for large arrays ( >1 MB ) with large ratio of duplicating data this optimization will gain more than lose.

Comment: I guess in that case it depends on whether the vertex assembly stage is your bottleneck or the memory upload to your graphics card is it. It just feels like a lot of additional processing is required for simply mapping colors to primitives. But for large data, there will almost certainly be a noticeable performance increase, when drastically reducing the amount of memory being transferred to the video memory.

Comment: On the other side, what is your update frequency? How often does the buffer change? Each frame? each n frames? Because you could double buffer this and upload in a second thread in parallel, so only a delay in data visibility would be noticeable, but no frame lagging.